# rosws problem fuerte

Tags: ros, rosws, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I have installed ROS successfully and also debian package for rosws. I have also setup a workspace for ROS with the command rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte. But after using the command mkdir ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox when I use rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox and I get an error stating command requires a target workspace. Kindly help me.........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41198/rosws-problem-fuerte/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to execute

```
source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh
```

as stated at the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays), section 'Creating a new overlay'.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-01-10**:
Even after executing this command, the $ROS_WORKSPACE is not set. I'm using Groovy under Ubuntu 12.10 32b. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem as described by the original post, but the ROS version is Groovy. Yes, I did run the setup.bash of the new workspace, but still I got the message:

*ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.*

I discovered, that I had to run *rosws set* inside the workspace directory, i.e.

*rosws set ~/ros_workspace/sandbox*

does not work, but

*cd ~/ros_workspace/; rosws set sandbox*

does work

---

Originally posted by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) with karma: 268 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-06**:
Now I understand the reason for this behaviour. For some reason, ros_workspace/setup.bash did not set $ROS_WORKSPACE. Any ideas why?

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-01-10**:
@r0nald Have you found out why $ROS_WORKSPACE was not set? I have the same problem (Groovy, Ubuntu 12.10 32b)

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-12**:
Im not sure about rosbuild, but I wound out that in case of catkin build system, $ROS_WORKSPACE is not meant to be set by default and it is not necessary to set it unless you want command 'roscd' to take you to workspace from anywhere.

**Comment by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on 2013-01-12**:
@r0nald Thanks! It's good to know it's not necessary. I was afraid some tools would kick the bucket because they missed this var.

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2013-01-21**:
i could not understand why going into the workspace directory to set it worked!, but sure it did.